# How to dismiss dropdown menu in WordPress template on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a Wordpress template and one of the features is a dropdown menu in the header. You click the arrow to open it, and it remains open until you click the arrow to close it. But, when you click on one of the links, it still remains open on the next page. You have to click the arrow to close it.

I would like the dropdown menu to automatically close when navigating to a new page. Here is my js for the navigation... I'm following a tutorial from Lynda so I didn't write this code, but I haven't had enough experience with js to know which section of the code is doing what exactly.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

```
function initMainNavigation( container ) {
    // Add dropdown toggle that display child menu items.
    container.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a' ).after( '<button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">' + screenReaderText.expand + '</button>' );

// Toggle buttons and submenu items with active children menu items.
container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > button' ).addClass( 'toggle-on' );
container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > .sub-menu' ).addClass( 'toggled-on' );

container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) {
    var _this = $( this );
    e.preventDefault();
    _this.toggleClass( 'toggle-on' );
    _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
    _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
    _this.html( _this.html() === screenReaderText.expand ? screenReaderText.collapse : screenReaderText.expand );
} );
}

initMainNavigation( $( '.main-navigation' ) );

// Re-initialize the main navigation when it is updated, persisting any existing submenu expanded states.
$( document ).on( 'customize-preview-menu-refreshed', function( e, params ) {
    if ( 'primary' === params.wpNavMenuArgs.theme_location ) {
        initMainNavigation( params.newContainer );

    // Re-sync expanded states from oldContainer.
    params.oldContainer.find( '.dropdown-toggle.toggle-on' ).each(function() {
        var containerId = $( this ).parent().prop( 'id' );
        $( params.newContainer ).find( '#' + containerId + ' > .dropdown-toggle' ).triggerHandler( 'click' );
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is almost a year old, but I wanted to go ahead and post an answer just in case someone needs it in the future.

The following lines from your code are what's causing the toggles to stay open when you go to a new page.

```
// Toggle buttons and submenu items with active children menu items.
container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > button' ).addClass( 'toggle-on' );
container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > .sub-menu' ).addClass( 'toggled-on' );
```

When you navigate to a page that is part of a sub-menu, these lines automatically add the 'toggle-on' class to the appropriate toggle button and parent sub-menu of that page. If you comment out those lines, the sub-menus will close when you navigate to a new page.